# "The identity of the remote computer cannot be verified" pops too often

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

When I first connect to win7pro from win7home using RDP, the client says: "The identity of the remote computer cannot be verified". I check "don't ask again" and for the next 2-4 weeks all is fine. After that the message is shown again. Why is that? Does the server periodically change its identity or does the client periodically "forget" it?

Answer (score 1):

The computer caches your response when you check "Do not ask again." However, certain events can clear your cache, such as Windows Updates.

The reason you get the error is because the computer has a self-signed certificate which is, by default, not trusted by any other computer. This is not a big deal but for convenience, you could add a certificate if you have a Certificate Authority server or if you actually wanted to spend the money to get one from a company like Digicert or Verisign.

Comment: What other events can clear the cache? (WU was disabled long ago)

Comment: Tons can cause it to happen. Clearing "temporary internet files", using utilities like CCleaner, certain registry changes, differences auto-detected about the RDP connection itself, etc.